# Creating a data frame from a list of lists with empty lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have some lists `lst1` and `lst2` and we want to create a data frame from them. So:

```
lst1 = ['Apple', 'Orange']
lst2 = []
```

When I try to create a data frame from these lists, it is empty:

```
import pandas as pd
df_output = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst1, lst2)),
               columns = ["lst1", "lst2" ])
```

Is there any easy way to add the `lst2` column even though it is empty?

Comment: Do you want the empty list to be the second column or the second row?

Comment: @ddejohn: second column

Comment: Replace zip with zip_longest from itertools.

Comment: @ayhan while that's a more general solution, I don't think it's necessary here when `pd.Series` can do the job sufficiently well.

Comment: @ddejohn I don't really agree that pd.Series does the job really well here because you end up calling transpose. That's one of the most inefficient methods in pandas and brings a lot of problems (your numeric columns will turn into objects etc). I am ok with reopening though.

Comment: That's a fair assessment, assuming OP's use-case is actually more complex than this, which would be a fair assumption.

Comment: @ayhan I think you should add your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more appropriate way to do this, but this'll work:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame(map(pd.Series, (lst1, lst2)), index=["lst1", "lst2"]).T
     lst1 lst2
0   Apple  NaN
1  Orange  NaN
```